# Как сделать массив экземпляров класса с полем-мьютексом?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

Есть класс `A`. У него есть поле `Mutex m_mutex;` - вопрос: как создать глобальный массив экземпляров класса `A`, у него есть конструктор, который принимает одно число. Пишется ошибка - попытка доступа к удаленной функции. Подозреваю, что проблема с move-семантикой для mutex - это запрещено.

Comment: Смотря какой массив. Если обычный, то будет пофиг ему на move.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
#include <mutex>

class A {
    std::mutex m_mutex;

public:
    A(int x) {}
};

A array[3] = {{1}, {2}, {7}};

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

То есть нужно явно указать аргумент конструктора каждого элемента массива.